# detect if user is moving

Tags: android

I would like to detect if a user is moving - either walking or jumping

I have found this code example

```
private final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        double calibration = SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY;

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            double x = event.values[0];
            double y = event.values[1];
            double z = event.values[2];

            double a = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)
                    + Math.pow(z, 2)));
            currentAcceleration = Math.abs((float) (a - calibration));
```

And it gives readings between 0.01 and 0.2 G's - can I use this example for detecting movement??
Perhaps a bit off topic? - sorry if it is!

Comment: Sure, you can try to detect a pattern in the data you get from there. If it is like up and down all the time it's probably movement. All you need to find now is a function to calculate the probability of movement based on the data you get. Research papers like http://www.mbeckler.org/coursework/2007-2008/senior_project_paper.pdf have probably some info on that topic

Comment: The thing to do is take this and add a little more code around it, put it on your device and walk around and see if it works.  Now the x,y,z you have is acceleration.  You will need velocity, which is v=acceleration times time and position which is velocity times time squared.   Or a, v=at, & x=vt*t       Enjoy Cliff

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a LOG file and write all data that changed to make your simple algorithm

1. you don't need to detect in super deep detail like 0.000000001, just need to detect 2 floating point like

   int estimateX = (int)(x*100);
2. keep log when it's move in wide range like from 0.75 to 0.80 (If you ask how do we know the range, yes, you need to walk and see)
3. Keep Walking